# Процедура авторизации/логина

Tags: c#

Для работы с WEB-api и недопущения взлома, каждая сессия клиента должна авторизоваться на сервере,
при пмощи вызова GET функции login с параметрами в заголовке
User string, содержит email
AType int 1=google, 0=fireBase, 2=FaceBook (тип авторизации)
Token - GUID, который вернула система аутентификации
функция:
проверяет правильность переданного токена
добавляет запись в список активных сессий с присвоением GUID сессии
возвращает в теле ответа GUID сессии, в формате JSON

Помогите не пойму как сделать

Comment: `Помогите не пойму как сделать` сделать что конкретно?

Comment: Как это с параметрами в заголовке?
авторизацию сессии на сервере

Comment: заголовок - это часть Http запроса. Там можно всякое передавать, например тип контента или токен авторизации

Comment: Мне вот дали задание, а я вообще не могу с ним разобраться

Comment: ну начните с начала. Вы web проект можете создать? Там при создании можно уже указать OAuth провайдеры, типа Google / Facebook, ну или просто можете [погуглить документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: У меня ASP.NET MVC

Comment: ну здорово, значит вам надо гуглить документацию ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

Все просто, ваш сервис должен авторизировать клиента полученным от него токеном. 
Это называется Bearer авторизация ... т.е. передачи токена в заголовке (Authorization: Bearer [token]). 
Клиент передает в заголовке вам токен, вы его в своем сервисе получаете и проверяете. 
вы можете использовать метод GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync для проверки подписанного Google JWT.
Ну и в сервисе добавить что то вроде этого, для JWT авторизации

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // укзывает, будет ли валидироваться издатель при валидации токена
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        // строка, представляющая издателя
                        ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,

                        // будет ли валидироваться потребитель токена
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        // установка потребителя токена
                        ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                        // будет ли валидироваться время существования
                        ValidateLifetime = true,

                        // установка ключа безопасности
                        IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                        // валидация ключа безопасности
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    };
                });

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```